# Is it possible for a Windows batch file to get its own name _as the user typed it_?

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a bash script, the `$0` variable gives the name of the script as the user typed it. For example, if the user invokes the script `foo` with:

```
$ ../bar/foo
```

…then in the script, `$0` would be `"../bar/foo”`.

In Windows .bat files, however, the similar variable **`%0`** and its [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797983/can-a-windows-batch-file-determine-its-own-file-name) [variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357315/how-to-get-list-of-arguments) all seem to give subsets of the bat file’s **expanded canonical path** — or at they they do on Windows 11.

For example, in the example above, `%0` produces something along the lines of `C:\Users\paul\whatever\blah\bar\foo.bat`, not `..\bar\foo` as desired.

---

It is useful to have the name of the current script *as the user typed it* when generating help / usage messages to suggest alternate invocations, e.g.:

```
$ ../bar/foo --zonkle

Zonkle is unavailable on this system. Try the wonkle option instead:

  ../bar/foo --wonkle

$
```

It this possible on Windows?

Comment: Short answer: No. You can strip the extension, but I don't think there is any way of getting the relative path.

Comment: If all you need is to know the script name, %~n0 is what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks @T3RR0R. Unfortunately no, what I need is the whole path, as in the example. The idea here is to give the user an alternate invocation of the command which they can copy & paste and have it work, no further fussing with paths. Looks like that’s a convenience I just won’t be able to offer, which is not the end of the world.